# an external button to modify a component in react

Tags: reactjs

i have read and practice with a tutorial but i have tried to make something else and i can t. i explain:

in my app i have have two component `<ColoredBlock />`  whose code is:

```
    class ColoredBlock extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.changeColor = this.changeColor.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      color: 'red'
    };
  }
  changeColor() {
    const newColor = this.state.color === 'red' ? 'blue' : 'red';
    this.setState({
      color: newColor
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (

      <div ref={this.maref} className="App-headers"   style={{ height: '200px', width: '200px', backgroundColor: this.state.color}}>

        <ChangeColorButton  clickHandler={this.changeColor} currentColor={this.state.color}></ChangeColorButton>

      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default ColoredBlock;
```

Each component `<ColoredBlock />` has a button as a child to modify the background color and all is working fine but

i have created an external button. This button is not a parent and not a child of my component

i d like , when i click on my button modify the background of one of my element  but i cant have access to my element... i know that getElementById doesn t work and i have tried with 'ref' but i can t.  Some helps please?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define color state and function to change this state somewhere in parent component of both ColoredBlock and your button and pass it down as props. 
It might look ugly thought. That's when redux and all that stuff comes in handy. 
 Also you can use [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)